# Combine lists of different lengths

Tags: r

I am new to R and started learning two weeks ago. I want to take a list of tropical cyclone counts for various years (where some years are absent, because there were no tropical cyclones) and create a list with a column of every year from 1907-2013 and a column of the number of tropical cyclones.
In the example I include the list of occurrences to 1973 (before 1912 there were none).

```
   Year  Count

1  1912    1
2  1913    1
3  1921    1
4  1940    1
5  1953    1
6  1958    1
7  1959    1
8  1960    1
9  1966    1
10 1969    1
11 1971    1
12 1973    2
```

I tried using a for loop and if/else statement, but it does not work. I get the message "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length" and "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used."

```
tc.SP=matrix(0,len.tc.yr,2)
tc.SP[,1]=tc.year.list

for (i in 1:len.tc.yr)  #107 yrs (1907-2013)
{
   if (tc.SP5.count[,1] == tc.SP[,1])  #tc.SP5.count is various years of TC occ.
  {tc.SP[,2]= tc.SP5.count[,2]}  
  else
  {tc.SP[,2]= 0}
}
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say list, i'm going to assume you want to create a data.frame. Let's say the data above is in a data.frame called `cyclone`. The easiest way to create a data.frame for every year is just to merge it with a complete list. For example

```
cyclone.full <- merge(cyclone, data.frame(Year=1907:2013), all=T)
```

Here the data.frames will automatically merge on the Year column because both sets have that column. This will put NA values in all the missing years. If you want the default to be 0, you can do

```
cyclone.full$Count[is.na(cyclone.full$Count)] <- 0
```

Then yo uget

```
head(cyclone.full)

#   Year Count
# 1 1907     0
# 2 1908     0
# 3 1909     0
# 4 1910     0
# 5 1911     0
# 6 1912     1
```

Comment: Yes, this answered my question. Thank you for the good explanation!